# Unpacking firmware

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, firmware, linux

I have a ROM dump firmware which must be reversed (as a task). Binwalk output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
88            0x58            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x535A17E8, created: 2015-05-13 06:08:01, image size: 1168920 bytes, Data Address: 0x80002000, Entry Point: 0x80006230, data CRC: 0x54A2AE00, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Moxa-IW awk series"
152           0x98            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 3392000 bytes
1169108       0x11D6D4        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 5833114 bytes, 806 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2015-05-13 06:07:57
7005944       0x6AE6F8        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 2733378 bytes, 330 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2015-05-13 06:07:58
```

After extract data and decompress LZMA, I have binary file "98", binwalk output for it:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1866012       0x1C791C        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 4
2169826       0x211BE2        mcrypt 2.5 encrypted data, algorithm: " !0B", keysize: 12290 bytes, mode: "B",
2605176       0x27C078        Linux kernel version "2.6.31--LSDK-WLAN-10.2.85 () #1 PREEMPT Wed May 13 14:00:35 CST 2015 "
2613200       0x27DFD0        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 2015-05-13 06:00:00
2693056       0x2917C0        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
2724896       0x299420        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
3024579       0x2E26C3        Neighborly text, "neighbor %.2x%.2x.%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x lost on port %d(%s)(%s)"
3391488       0x33C000        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "/dev", file name length: "0x00000005", file size: "0x00000000"
3391604       0x33C074        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "/dev/console", file name length: "0x0000000D", file size: "0x00000000"
3391728       0x33C0F0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "/root", file name length: "0x00000006", file size: "0x00000000"
3391844       0x33C164        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
```

Before offset 1866012 there are some unrecognized data.
When I unpack this binary, I get kernel configure file, cpio archive and some binary 1C791C.crt, as I understand it, which contains kernel files. How i can correctly extract bootloader and Linux kernel files?
See:

- [Firmware.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zEJGtGaIAxQhXwK1ygwuU1jp-HUpYXEP/view?usp=sharing)
- [98.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyGJpwz3l-9MnuQ_xhbxWCPkCsD8YbYD/view?usp=sharing)
- [1C791.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nqgCcJ3zr0n77M-yXXRtq0f5dRE764Xh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: aren't you supposed to do this "task" yourself?

Comment: could you download 98.bin in IDA??

Answer (score 3):

If you extract this file in the right way, you will get linux root filesystem as it is.(2 types in this case)
[image: root FS 1]

[image: root FS 2]
I don't see any kind of bootloader, the dump seems to be only the root fs  and kernel part.

If you open file "98.bin" again with 7zip, it will open again, thats because of this data at the end of file:
[image: entropy 98.bin]
The .cer file you get from binwalk is not real certificate file, is just a coincidence of hex header 0x3082, which is used for certificates, but in this case is just pure code and has not the cert structure.

Comment: could you describe the "right way" in a bit more detail?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky sorry for delay I was really disconnected. The right way seems to be just clicking right button and open with 7zip, very easy task.